# Using dynamic_cast on a template function

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template <typename T> void findType(T *obj, TFmxChildrenList *children)
{
    if(children == NULL || children->Count < 1)
        obj = NULL;
    else
    {
        for(int i=0; i < children->Count; i++)
        {
            if(children->Items[i]->ClassNameIs(T::ClassName()))
                obj = dynamic_cast<T*>(children->Items[i]);
            else
                this->findType<T>(obj, children->Items[i]->Children);
        }
    }
}
```

Called By:

```
    TRectangle *rc;
    findType<TRectangle>(rc, children);
```

What I am trying to do is at run time descend through an object to find an object of a type. However when casting it to that type it returning a rather a different object compared to if I did a dynamic_cast(...) as the memory address of the root object is different between them both.

I was wondering if there was something that I am doing wrong or if it is possible to do this?

Comment: You should pass `obj` by reference if you want to modify it

Comment: @Jarod42 Agreed, but he can't drop the NULL hammer on obj with a reference. I suggest as an alternate go with a reference, change return type to bool, and return false on error. Probably a lot safer than tossing NULL pointers around

Comment: @user4581301: Returning `T*` seems even better.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oddly I didn't even consider that option. Wow. I really am sick.

Comment: Using `ClassNameIs()` and `dynamic_cast` together is redundant and unnecessary, and does not detect descendants that inherit from `T` (and thus could be casted to `T*`) but have a different `ClassName()` value than `T`. Just use `dynamic_cast` by itself instead: `obj = dynamic_cast<T*>(children->Items[i]); if (!obj) this->findType<T>(obj, children->Items[i]->Children);`

Comment: Sorry, where is the ``this`` coming from? Isn't findType a free function?